# Medieval Society Working With Nymph-infused Animals

Tags: society, fantasy-races

This question was inspired by a comment on one of my recent questions ([Finding Nymphs Before Predators](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195608/finding-nymphs-before-predators)), which I am quoting here:

"Humans also have human intelligence and the ability to understand humans. They are also capable of both cooperating with and posing a danger to humans. If nymph-enhanced animals are human-equivalent intelligence, at least some should be able to see the survival benefits of civilization and cooperate to control wild monsters and obtain nymphs to produce more of their own kind."-Christopher James Huff

**Context:**
Magic from an alternate world is bleeding through into this one, combining with the built-up residual life force in certain areas (cemeteries, battlefields, tar pits, and the like) and forming beings called Nymphs. Nymphs appear as human women in their prime, cannot be poisoned or diseased, can breathe air and water with equal ease, wade through lava flows and stroll through Arctic wastelands (they're basically unaffected by hot and cold), speak and understand any human language, and they know any plant or animal in their environment.

Now, what do Nymphs have to do with animals? Don't worry, I'm getting there. All Nymphs are born naive, peaceful, curious, with childlike love and awe of nature, a deep longing for purpose, and a deep belief in fate. The last one causes Nymphs to go on a journey after being "born," the purpose of which is to see the wonders of nature and to find their purpose.

Sooner or later, a Nymph either finds a predator or finds a purpose, and *that* is when Nymph infusion occurs. You see, since Nymphs are biologically immortal and nearly impervious to harm, they have a built-in population check, an urge to return to nature by *being eaten*. Oddly enough, this is not the end for a Nymph.

When a Nymph is eaten, her potent natural energies infuse the consumer, and her spirit passes on her knowledge of linguistics and nature (flora and fauna). As an example, a Nymph-infused tiger is supernaturally stealthy, becoming invisible in shadows, and is fast and strong enough to A) catch up to a running horse and B) rend that armored knight on the horse's back. That and its understanding of human language and nature makes it quite formidable.

**My question:** Will an early medieval society accept dangerous (but intelligent) predators into their society?

I'm thinking of things like wolves, bears, and European lions, species natural to Europe. By the way, Russia counts as part of Europe, so Siberian tigers are a possibility. As for early medieval society, I think the Eastern Roman (Byzantine) Empire in Constantinople best fits my vision of a large and relatively advanced (yet still medieval) kingdom.

**References (Questions You Might Find Helpful To Look At):**

[Finding Nymphs Before Predators](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195608/finding-nymphs-before-predators)

[Nymphs and Humans: Preventing Anarchy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195737/nymphs-and-humans-preventing-anarchy)

Thank you for your input and feedback, I really appreciate it! Oh, and if you decide to VTC or close-vote, please give me an explanation so I can both improve this question and make better ones in the future.

Comment: There has never been a single and standardized early medieval human society. On top of that a society is made by individuals, each and every with their own standards. I think you are just calling for opinions here

Comment: @Tantalus'touch.: first up, this is a quote, I can't edit it, and if you click on the linked question you can find its original location and hopefully make more sense of it. Also, "no it isn't. (Including contrarians)." makes no sense to me, what are you referring to?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, just added to the OP: "As for early medieval society, I think the Eastern Roman (Byzantine) Empire in Constantinople best fits my vision of a large and relatively advanced (yet still medieval) kingdom." So, I _am_ trying to be specific. Thank you for your input, I didn't realize there was a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you'd made it up as part of your setting, comments deleted. Down-vote withdrawn 'till the morning and I'm more awake.

Comment: I don't think you have solved the problem. As I stated, even a very specific society is made of several individuals, each with their own standards. Victorian England has the fame of being a prude society, yet Oscar Wilde is all but a prude.

Comment: I have to agree. "Will society accept X?" is not really answerable with facts. "What can X do to be more acceptable to society?" would be a subtly different but imho more answerable question.

Comment: They are lots of stories in the middle age have monster hunters you should read some of those.